# sub2ind with 3D matrices

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, matrix, indexing

given a code, for example, like this

```
A=rand(10,10); 

indX(:,:,1)=[2,3;1,6];  indX(:,:,2)=[2,5;2,6]; 
indY(:,:,1)=[4,6;2,3];  indY(:,:,2)=[7,5;3,4]; 

for i=1:2
    for j=1:2

        ind=sub2ind(size(A), indX(:,:,i), indY(:,:,j));
        figure,imagesc(A(ind));

    end
end
```

I would like to obtain the same result, without using a for loop. Is there any faster way?

Comment: Creating the figure window and displaying the image in it is the slowest part of your code by far. That is orders of magnitude more expensive than the loops and the indexing. You cannot speed this up.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ok thanks. In my code I don't display the matrices A, but I need them, this was only an example. With huge matrices and a huge number of indices this for loop can be very slow

Comment: Yes, the indexing would be expensive, it needs to copy values. It's not the looping though. 20 years ago, removing loops usually sped up code. But this has not been true for a long time now. MATLAB has come a long way since then. Run the profiler, see what part of your code is the most expensive. Likely it is whatever you do with the matrices A, unless you just store them.

Answer (score 0):

```
N=10;  % size square A
L=10;    % height nX nY
M=2;    % size nX nY square base

A=randi(N,N)

nX=randi([1 N],M,M,L);
nY=randi([1 N],M,M,L);
```

**1.-  Just to make sure it's understood how imagesc works**

This is an NxN pixelated matrix
figure;

imagesc(A)

[image]

And this is just a single pixel sizing the entire image

```
figure;
image(A(3))
```

[image]

with the colour of your choice indeed, yet it's just one colour for the entire figure. Is this really what you are up to? or do you intend to switch on and change single pixels of the initial imagesc(A), holding A in place?

```
close all
```

Something tells me that you really want is the 2nd one:

- changing single pixels,
- or filling up the entire matrix one pixel at
  a time,
- or just switching on one pixels at a time,
- or swapping pixels,
- or make them blink

whichever of the above, or any other not included,

YET WHILE holding the entire `imagesc(A)` in figure, not just `imagesc(A(4))`.

Correct me if not this way but if you really wanted to shift the entire figure like a semaphore through a `colorbar` there wouldn't be need for the code posted in the question anyway.

So let's proceed with such assumption.

**2.- Obtaining All X Y combinations**

is there really any need for `nX` `nY` to be square ?

```
n2X=reshape(nX,[M*M L])';
n2Y=reshape(nY,[M*M L])';

[X,Y]=meshgrid([1:L],[1:L]);
W=[X(:) Y(:)];

Lx=[];Ly=[];
for k=1:1:size(W,1)
    Lx=[Lx n2X(W(k,1),:)];
    Ly=[Ly n2Y(W(k,2),:)];
end

L=[Lx;Ly];
```

Now `L` contains all pairs of indexs that you generated with a double for loop

**3.- Make it blink**

Displaying results, since it's not clear whether you want to switch on/off off/on blink single pixels, or swap, or whatever .. I go for blinking.

```
figure;
ax=gca
hold all

hm=imagesc(A)
ax.DataAspectRatio=[1 1 1];

for k=1:1:size(L,2)
    d=A(L(1,k),L(2,k))
    A(L(1,k),L(2,k))=0;
    imagesc(A);
    drawnow % limitrate nocallbacks
   % pause(.5);
    A(L(1,k),L(2,k))=d;
    imagesc(A);
    drawnow % limitrate nocallbacks
    % pause(.5);

end
```

**4.- only call figure once**

and there's no need to call command figure inside busy for loops either

I know you said no for loops, but building the sequence of all indexes in advance is the key point that is going to save your code the time you ask for in the question.

Thanks for reading my answer.

Comment: It’s always a good idea to read the comments before posting an answer. *“In my code I don't display the matrices A, but I need them, this was only an example.”*

Comment: Dear Cris, even when we thing we don't, we are always using matrices.